# Let $a$ be a complex number that is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$ and let $r$ be a rational number. Prove that $a^r$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $a$ be a complex number that is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$ and let
>   $r$ be a rational number. Prove that $a^r$ is algebraic over $\Bbb
> Q$.

Let $r = \frac{p}{q}$ where $q \neq 0$.  Then $h(x) = x^q - a \in \Bbb Q(a)[x]$ is a minimal polynomial in $\Bbb Q(a)$.  Then because $[F(a^r):F]=[F(a^r):F(a)][F(a):F] = \deg h(x) \cdot \deg f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial in $\Bbb Q[x]$, this shows that it is a finite extension $\Rightarrow$ algebraic.

The fact that $a$ is complex seems to be irrelevant based on this proof, did I miss something in my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the complex numbers is simply a convenient way of fixing an ambient field. And you probably want $h(x)=x^q-a^p$, so that $h(a^r)=0$.

Also, $h$ need not be the minimal polynomial of $a^r$ over $\mathbb{Q}(a^p)$, but since $h(a^r)=0$ we can at least say that $[\mathbb{Q}(a^r):\mathbb{Q}(a^p)]\leq \mathrm{deg}(h)$. This is enough to finish the proof using the tower rule.

Comment: Could you explain how you would use $[\mathbb{Q}(a^r):\mathbb{Q}(a)]\leq \mathrm{deg}(h)$ to prove this?  I can't see how it would be done.

Comment: The same way as in your argument: $[\mathbb{Q}(a^r):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(a^r):\mathbb{Q}(a)][\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]\leq \mathrm{deg}(h)\mathrm{deg}(f)$.

Comment: @carmichael561 How do you know that $Q(a^r)$ is an extension of $Q(a)$? Do we know that $a \in Q(a^r)$ ?

Comment: I suppose it should be $\mathbb{Q}(a^p)$, though fortunately this doesn't change anything important.

Comment: @carmichael561 I am sorry, i still dont understand. Now you need to prove that $Q(a^p)$ is a finite extension of $Q(a)$ or $Q$

Comment: Well, $a^p\in\mathbb{Q}(a)$, so $\mathbb{Q}(a^p)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$.